# Trouble with authorization in NestJS using jwt and passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, nestjs

I have a ruby on rails api that will connect to a nestjs api that i'm making from scratch.
I will create a jwt token on rails and use it as the authorization, using the same signature on both projects. For now, i'm testing only via postman calling the NestJS api, but it is returning "UNAUTHORIZED" on every request. Here's a little bit of my code:

**jwt.doctor.strategy.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

@Injectable({})
export class JwtDoctorStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  'jwt.doctor',
) {
  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: config.get('JWT_DOCTOR_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  validate(payload: any) {
    console.log({
      payload,
    });

    return payload;
  }
}
```

PS: i created two strategies because i have different signatures for different cases. The other one is very similar to this one, but for now i'm only tested the one i provided above.

**doctor.controller.ts**

```js
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('doctors')
export class DoctorController {
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt.doctor'))
  @Get('me')
  getMe() {
    return 'User info';
  }
}
```

Am i missing something? I'm creating the jwt token in the console for test purposes, and its being validated ok on the jwt website. Would appreciate very much any insights (:

Answer (score 0):

We can pass an options object in the call to `super()` to customize the behavior of the passport strategy. In this example, the passport-local strategy by default expects properties called username and password in the request body. Pass an options object to specify different property names, for example: `super({ usernameField: 'email' })`

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
       usernameField: 'email' // your strategy here in super
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, email: payload.email };
  }
}
```

Also assuming that your other Modules are importing the `AuthModule` in order to have access to the AuthService you could just re-export the `PassportModule`:

```
const passportModule = PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' });

@Module({
  imports: [
    passportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [passportModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```